# Python click module: is the repetition of 'name' in 'from module import name as name' necessary?

Tags: python, import

In the newly installed Pythons module [click](https://github.com/pallets/click) source code I have encountered many lines with import statements like:

```
from .types import BOOL as BOOL
from .types import Choice as Choice
from .types import DateTime as DateTime
from .types import File as File
from .types import FLOAT as FLOAT
from .types import FloatRange as FloatRange
from .types import INT as INT
from .types import IntRange as IntRange
from .types import ParamType as ParamType
from .types import Path as Path
from .types import STRING as STRING
from .types import Tuple as Tuple
from .types import UNPROCESSED as UNPROCESSED
from .types import UUID as UUID
```

I haven't seen usage of such syntax yet so made an Internet search to find out what it does and why.

I have found out that the dot `.` before the module name is necessary as it forces the import to use the modules own local directory for getting the module instead of loading a module from the collection of in Python already existing ones with same name.

But I haven't yet found out which sense has the repetition of the method name while using `as`. Up to now I was assuming that this syntax is used for renaming the imported method, but this is here not the case.

Could the `as method_name` just be skipped from `from .module_name import method_name as method_name`? Or will this have some effect I am not aware of?

Comment: The `as ...` doesn't make sense here. I can only guess that this was maybe created by some IDE or tool automatically (the alphabetic order suggests that).

Comment: @MichaelButscher Do git blame and have a look at the referenced issue.

Comment: @KellyBundy Thank you. So it is mypy's fault (as described at https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/1879).

Answer (score 0):

In order to mark this question as answered here an answer which reflects the outcome of the discussion between @MichaelButscher and @KellyBundy in the comments to the question:

The reason for the name repetitions found in the via pip installable module seem to be to fit to the requirements of passing mypy tests for checking uploaded code. Here an excerpt of discussion about it on [github](https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/1879)

> This is about the --no-implicit-reexport flag: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-no-implicit-reexport. Click's **init**.py has a bunch of lines like from .module import Name. With that flag on, mypy doesn't treat such names as being re-exported, and to make it accept the code you need to do from .module import Name as Name.